How big a class of lines can a non-linear transformation map to itself?
Edit:  In the original version of this question, I wrote "lines through the origin" instead of "lines"; as Alexandre Eremenko points out in his answer, this makes the question too easy.  (See also Thomas Rot's comment.)   I've edited, and I hope the question is now more sensible.

In ${\mathbb R}^2$, let ${\cal L}$ be a set of lines.
Let $T:{\mathbb R}^2\rightarrow {\mathbb R}^2$ be a map such that:
a)  $T$ is bijective.
b)  $T(0,0)=(0,0)$
c)  $T$ takes lines in ${\cal L}$ to lines in ${\cal L}$.
Question: For which sets ${\cal L}$ must $T$ be linear?
Remark 1:  When ${\cal L}$ is the set of all lines,  then I believe the answer is that $T$ must be linear.
Remark 2:  I am particularly interested in the case where ${\cal L}$ consists of all lines with absolute slope $>1$.
Motivation: I am trying to minimize the assumptions needed to derive the linearity of the Lorentz transformations in special relativity.   I am reasonably happy to assume that two inertial observers must agree on whether a passing car is accelerating, which means that a Lorentz transformation should take worldlines to worldlines (i.e. the timelike lines of Remark 2).  But I don't see an equally good reason to assume that it takes all lines to lines, so I can't directly apply Remark 1.

Don't you want any type of continuity on T? What about a map on R^2 where T(x,y)=(x,y) when x,y are both non-zero, and T(x,y)=T(y,x) when either x or y is zero?

Related: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.01762

@LucGuyot:  Thank you for making sure I saw your update.

Edited to provide a stronger result.
A set $\mathcal{X}$ of affine subspaces of $\mathbb{R^n}$ is invariant under translations if $S \in \mathcal{X}$ implies $v + S \in \mathcal{X}$ for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
A theorem of Borchers and Egerfeldt (1972) gives a complete answer when $\mathcal{L}$ is invariant under translations:

Theorem [4, Satz 1].
Let $n \ge 2$ and let $\mathcal{L}$ be a set of one-dimensional affine subspaces (a.k.a lines) of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is invariant under translations.
Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the set of all injective maps $T$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $T$ maps every line in $\mathcal{L}$ onto a line of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and satisfies $T(0) = 0$.
Then every $T \in \mathcal{T}$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear if and only if the subset $A = \{a \in \mathbb{R}^n \, \vert \, \mathbb{R}a \in \mathcal{L} \}$ satisfies both of the following two conditions:

$A$ is not contained in the zero set of a degenerate quadratic form.
The subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by all the elements of the form $\frac{a_i}{a_j}$ with $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in A$ and $a_j \neq 0$ is $\mathbb{R}$.



My original answer below turns out to be a known result of Egerfeldt [2] that was subsequently and significantly improved in [3], [4] and also in [5] in other directions.
Here is a criterion showing that $T$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear provided $\mathcal{L}$ is large enough:

Claim. Let $n \ge 2$ and let $\mathcal{L}$ be a set of one-dimensional affine subspaces (a.k.a lines) of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is invariant under translations.
Let $T$ be a bijective map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Assume that $T$ maps every line in $\mathcal{L}$ onto a line of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and that $T(0) = 0$. Assume moreover that the subset $A = \{a \in \mathbb{R}^n \, \vert \, \mathbb{R}a \in \mathcal{L} \}$ has non-empty interior in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Disclaimer. The conditions of the claim are not necessary, see the theorem of Borchers and Egerfeldt (1972) at the top.
I have just made this exercise of revisiting Scherk's proof of the fundamental theorem of affine geometry [1] with a view to relax conditions on $\mathcal{L}$ as much as possible.
We shall denote by $A^{\circ}$ the interior of $A$.
Our assumptions on $T$ in the above claim imply that there is a map $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \times A \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
T(\lambda a) = \varphi(\lambda, a) T(a)
$$
for every $a \in A$ and every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.
Note also that:

$0 \notin A$.
If $a, b \in A$ are two linearily independent vectors, then so are $T(a)$ and $T(b)$.
If $L, L' \in \mathcal{L}$ are parallel lines, then so are $T(L)$ and $T(L')$.

Only the last assertion is not obvious if $n > 2$. This is addressed by Lemma 1 below.
Our proof relies on a series of five lemmas.

Lemma 1. Let $T$ and $A$ be as in the above claim. Let $a, b \in A$ be two linearily independent vectors. Then $T(\mathbb{R}a + \mathbb{R}b + c)$ is a plane for every $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$.


Proof. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}a + \mathbb{R}b + c$. Then $x$ lies on a line of $\mathcal{L}$ that intersects both $\mathbb{R}a + c$ and $\mathbb{R}b + c$. Thus $T(x) \in \mathbb{R}T(a) + \mathbb{R}T(b) + T(c)$.


Lemma 2. Let $T$ and $A$ be as in the above claim. Let $a, b \in A^{\circ} \cup \{0\}$. Then $T(a + b) = T(a) + T(b)$.


Proof. Since $T(0) = 0$, we can assume, without loss of generality, that $a$ and $b$ are non-zero vectors.
If $a$ and $b$ are linearily independent, the quadrilateral  with vertices $\{0, a, a + b, b\}$ is a non-degenerate parallelogram whose
sides are included in lines of $\mathcal{L}$. Thus the quadrilateral $\{0, T(a), T(a + b), T(b)\}$ is a parallelogram, so that $T(a + b) = T(a) + T(b)$.
If $a$ and $b$ are not linearily independent, then pick some $c \in A^{\circ}$ that is linearily independent from $a$
and such that both $a + c$ and $b + c$ belong to $A^{\circ}$.
Using the previous step, we have on one hand $$T(a + (b + c)) = T(a) + T(b + c) = T(a) + T(b) + T(c),$$
and on the other hand
$$T((a + b) + c) = T(a + b) + T(c).$$
Thus $T(a + b) = T(a) + T(b)$.

Lemma 2 can be strengthened in the following way:

Lemma 3. Let $T$ and $A$ be as in the above claim. Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Then $T(a + b) = T(a) + T(b)$, i.e., the map $T$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-linear over $\mathbb{R}^n$.


Proof. Let us assume first that $a \notin A^{\circ} \cup \{0\}$ and $b \in A^{\circ} \cup \{0\}$.
Then we can write $a = a' + b'$ where $a', b' \in  A^{\circ}$ are two linearily independent vectors.
Swapping $a'$ with $b'$ if needed, we can assume, without loss of generality,
that $a'$ and $b$ are linearily independent. The sides of the non-degenerate parallelograms with
vertices $\{0, b, a' + b, a'\}$ and $\{a', a' + b, a + b, a\}$ are all contained in lines of $\mathcal{L}$.
Therefore the images of these parallelograms under $T$ are non-degenerate parallelograms. Consequently,
the quadrilateral with vertices $\{0, T(b), T(a + b), T(a)\}$ is also a parallelogram, so that $T(a + b) = T(a) + T(b)$.
Let us assume now that $a, b \notin A^{\circ} \cup \{0\}$. Then we can write $b = b' + c'$ with $b', c' \in  A^{\circ}$.
Using the previous step together with Lemma 1, we obtain that
$$T(a + b) = T((a + b') + c') = T(a + b') + T(c') = T(a) + (T(b') + T(c')) = T(a) + T(b' + c'), $$
hence $T(a + b) = T(a) + T(b)$.
Since the remaining cases are already handled by Lemma 2, the proof is complete.


Lemma 4. Let $A$ and $\varphi$ be as above. Let $a, b \in A^{\circ}$.
Then $\varphi(\lambda, a) = \varphi(\lambda, b)$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.


Proof. Suppose first that $a$ and $b$ are linearily independent and that $a + b \in A^{\circ}$.
Using Lemma 2, we obtain on one hand,
$$T(\lambda(a + b)) = \varphi(\lambda, a + b)T(a + b) = \varphi(\lambda, a + b)T(a) + \varphi(\lambda, a + b)T(b).$$


Using again Lemma 2, we obtain on the other hand
$$T(\lambda(a + b)) = T(\lambda a) + T(\lambda b) = 
\varphi(\lambda, a)T(a) + \varphi(\lambda, b)T(b).$$


Since $T(a)$ and $T(b)$ are linearily independent, it follows  that $\varphi(\lambda, a + b) = \varphi(\lambda, a) = \varphi(\lambda, b)$.


Suppose now that $a$ and $b$ are two arbitrary vectors in $A^{\circ}$.
Then there is $c \in A^{\circ}$ such that $a + c \in A^{\circ}, b + c \in A^{\circ}$ and $c \notin \mathbb{R}a \cup \mathbb{R}b$.
Thanks to the previous step, we have $\varphi(\lambda, a) = \varphi(\lambda, c) = \varphi(\lambda, b)$.


Lemma 5. Let $A$ and $\varphi$ be as above and let
$a \in A^{\circ}$. Then the map $f: \lambda \mapsto \varphi(\lambda, a)$
is a field automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$, that is, $f$ is the identity on $\mathbb{R}$.


Proof. We certainly have $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.
Let $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$.
By Lemma 2, we have
$$T((\lambda + \mu)a) = T(\lambda a) + T(\mu a) = f(\lambda)T(a) + f(\mu)T(a) = (f(\lambda) + f(\mu))T(a).$$
Thus $f(\lambda + \mu) = f(\lambda) + f(\mu)$.
Assuming that $\lambda, \mu \neq 0$, Lemma 4 implies that
$$
T(\lambda \mu a) = T(\lambda (\mu a)) =  f(\lambda) T(\mu a) = f(\lambda)f(\mu)T(a)
$$
which yields $f(\lambda \mu) = f(\lambda)f(\mu)$.
To show that $f$ is the identity, it suffices to observe that $f$ is order-preserving ($f$ preserves squares and positive real numbers are squares)
and that $f$ fixes the subfield $\mathbb{Q}$ point-wise.

We are now in position to prove the claim.

Proof of the claim. By Lemma 3, the application $T$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-linear.
So it suffices to show that $T(\lambda a) = \lambda T(a)$ for every $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.
By Lemmas 4 and 5, and because $T(0) = 0$, we know that latter identity holds for every $\lambda$ if $a \in A^{\circ} \cup \{0\}$.
If $a \notin A^{\circ} \cup \{0\}$, then $a = a' + b'$ for some $a', b' \in  A^{\circ}$.
Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.
By Lemmas 3 and the previous remark, we have
$T( \lambda a) = T( \lambda a') + T( \lambda b') = \lambda T(a') + \lambda T(b') = \lambda (T(a') + T(b')) = \lambda T(a)$.



[1] P. Scherk, "On the fundamental theorem of affine geometry", 1962.

[2] G. Egerfeldt, "The Lorentz transformations: Derivation of linearity and scale factor", 1972.

[3] H. Borchers and G. Egerfeldt, "The Structure of Space-Time Transformations", 1972.

[4] H. Borchers and G. Egerfeldt, "Uber ein Problem der Relativitätsheorie:Wann sind die Punktabbildungen des $\mathbb{R}^n$ linear?", 1972.

[5] A. Chubarev and I. Pinelis, "Linearity of Space-Time Transformations Without the One-to-One, Line-onto-Line,
or Constancy-of-Speed-of-Light Assumptions", 2000.



What do you mean by "invariant under translations" and where in your proof is this condition used?

@IosifPinelis Dear Iosif, thank you very much your interest and your careful reading. I have now added a definition of what I meant by "$\mathcal{L}$ is invariant under translations": if $\mathcal{L}$ contains $a + \mathbb{R}b$ then $\mathcal{L}$ contains $a' + \mathbb{R}b$ for every $a' \in \mathbb{R}^n$. This assumption is satisfied when we consider all lines with a slopes lying in a specific range, as in OP's second question.   Admittedly, the use of this hypothesis is a bit hidden. It is implicitly used  to infer that the image of a parallelogram $P$ by $T$ is a parallelogram ...

... provided that the sides of $P$ are contained in lines of $\mathcal{L}$. More precisely: the sides of a parallelogram ${0, a, a + b, b}$ with $a, b \in A$ are included in lines of $\mathcal{L}$ since we have assumed that $\mathcal{L}$ is invariant under translations.

Concerning

Remark 2:  I am particularly interested in the case where ${\cal L}$ consists of all lines with absolute slope $>1$.

The following more general result is proved in this paper:

Let $n\ge2$ and $T$ be a mapping of $\Bbb R^n$ onto itself which maps every timelike line $\ell$ into an arbitrary line so that the image of every future ray of $\ell$ contains at least two distinct points or the same holds for every past ray of $\ell$. Then $T$ is affine.


This completely settles the question I cared about (and more!) though it leaves open the more general question that I actually asked.  I will be entirely delighted to award you this answer the bounty unless someone else comes along and answers (some approximation to) that more general question.

@StevenLandsburg : I am wondering why you awarded the bounty to another answer, which appears to provide a less general result than the one in my answer.

I remain very grateful for your answer, and the pointer to your paper.  The bounty was a close call, but (as best I can remember), it was at least partly because the other answer is more general than yours in the sense that it makes an assumption about all lines with slopes in some open interval, whereas yours (at least as stated) makes an assumption about all lines with slopes in a particular open interval.  (Though of course it's quite easy to see how to get from one to the other.)

@StevenLandsburg : Thank you for responding. However, I don't understand in what sense the other answer is more general, and why this was a close call. In particular, why are you saying that my result assumes a particular interval of slopes (I guess here you mean the 2D case)? In my paper with Chubarev, what we called the timelike lines are defined wrt an arbitrary nonempty open convex cone in $\mathbf R^n\setminus{0}$. Also, I do not see that "it's quite easy to" get my result from the less general result in the other answer.

First:  When I said that it was "quite easy to get from one result to the other", I meant that it was quite easy to get from your result to Luc Guyot's, not the other way around.  Second:  When I typed the comment above, I had unaccountably forgotten that your convex cone was as arbitrary as Luc Guyot's (my only excuse is that it was late at night), so what I said about generality there was certainly false.  Third:  As best as I can recall my actual reasoning, I weighed the greater generality of your answer against the greater simplicity of Luc Guyot's.  It was a close call.

@StevenLandsburg : Hmm ... Initially you said "I will be entirely delighted to award you this answer the bounty unless someone else comes along and answers (some approximation to) that more general question." So, your concern seems to have been about greater generality, rather than greater simplicity. But, according to your last comment, you awarded the bounty (and the acceptance) to a less general result based on simplicity. So, I am still confused.

You're asking me to reconstruct a thought process that I don't believe I can reconstruct.  I did carefully read your paper and understand your result when you first posted it.  There seem to have been moments a few days later when I forgot how general your result was.  I have no memory of whether or not the moment I awarded the bounty was one of those moments.  I'm sure that the other answer seemed to me to be substantially simpler than yours (and still does).   I don't remember what relative weights I placed on simplicity versus (my then-perception of) generality.   (CTD)

(CTD)  I might have forgotten about my earlier comment, which certainly was an accurate statement of my intentions at the time.  Or perhaps I remembered the comment and my intentions had changed.    There were, I thought, two very good answers and I would very much like to have accepted both of them.   I learned a lot from both of them, and I remain very grateful.  Thank you.

There are plenty of non-linear bijective transformations which map each line through the origin to itself.
Take any continuous increasing bijective function $f:[0,+\infty)\to[0,+\infty)$, and define your map in polar coordinates as
$$(r,\theta)\mapsto (f(r),\theta),\quad 0\mapsto 0.$$
You misread what the fundamental theorem of projective geometry says.

You are of course right.  The phrase ``through the origin" was a mistake.  Without that phrase, is there an interesting question here?

I'm unaccepting this answer to avoid deterring people from responding to the (hopefully) repaired version of the question.  I trust this won't be interpreted as an expression of annoyance --- I'm certainly grateful for your correction.

If a strong regularity condition is imposed, then even five lines are enough.

Let $T:\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^2$ be analytic,
and $\mathcal{L}$ a set of five pairwise non-parallel lines in the plane. Suppose each of the five lines belonging to $\mathcal{L}$ is mapped by $T$ into a line in $\Bbb{R}^2$, and the five lines containing the images are pairwise non-parallel. Moreover, suppose that there are three lines in $\mathcal{L}$ which are not concurrent. Then $T$ is an affine transformation.

Proof) Let $L_1,L_2,L_3\in\mathcal{L}$ be three lines that do not intersect at any single point. There exists an affine change of coordinates $A:\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^2$ that takes the other two lines into the coordinate axes. Thus $A(\mathcal{L})$ consists of the $x$-axis, the $y$-axis and three non-concurrent, non-parallel lines
$$L'_i: y=\ell_i(x):=m_ix+h_i\,\, i\in\{1,2,3\}$$
where the slopes $m_1,m_2,m_3$ are distinct and non-zero; and furthermore, affine univariate functions $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3$ never attain the same value at a point. Through relabeling $L_1,L_2,L_3$ if necessary, we may assume that $m_1\neq -m_2,-m_3$. Because if say $m_1=-m_2$, then $m_3\neq m_1,m_2$ would be distinct from the opposites of $m_1$ and $m_2$. Next, $T\circ A^{-1}$ maps the aforementioned five lines (the axes among them) into five non-parallel lines in $\Bbb{R}^2$ (each line is mapped into a line). Composing with a suitable change of coordinates $B$, we may assume that the map $B\circ T\circ A^{-1}$ maps each axis into itself. Therefore, by replacing $T$ with $B\circ T\circ A^{-1}$, there is no loss of generality in assuming that $T:\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^2$ preserves each of the axes: the second (resp. the first) component of $T$ is identically zero on the $x$-axis (resp. on the $y$-axis). Since the components of $T$ are analytic functions on $\Bbb{R}^2$, this means that the second (resp. the first) component is independent of $x$ (resp. independent of $y$). We conclude that $T(x,y)=(f(x),g(y))\,\,\forall (x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2$ for some univariate analytic functions $f,g:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$.
We next use the fact that there are three lines $\tilde{L}_1,\tilde{L}_2,\tilde{L}_3$, not parallel with each other or with an axis, for which $T(L'_i)\subseteq\tilde{L}_i\,\,\forall i\in\{1,2,3\}$. First, notice that, without any loss of generality, we may assume that $g$ is not constant: If it is, then $T(L'_1)=T(L'_2)=T(L'_3)=T(\Bbb{R}^2)$, and the former set is included in a horizontal line.  But it is also contained in three non-parallel lines. Hence that set must be a singleton in which case $T$ is a constant function, and thus affine. Next, denote the equations for $\tilde{L}_1,\tilde{L}_2,\tilde{L}_3$ by
$$\tilde{L}_i: y=\tilde{\ell}_i(x):=\tilde{m}_ix+\tilde{h}_i\,\, i\in\{1,2,3\}.$$
For $T(x,y)=(f(x),g(y))$, the containment $T(L'_i)\subseteq\tilde{L}_i$ amounts to
$\tilde{\ell}_i\circ f=g\circ\ell_i$. Notice that $\tilde{\ell}_i$ is non-constant, and hence invertible, as $g$ is non-constant.
This equation should hold for all $i\in\{1,2,3\}$, thus
$$
g=\tilde{\ell}_1\circ f\circ\ell_1^{-1}=\tilde{\ell}_2\circ f\circ\ell_2^{-1}=\tilde{\ell}_3\circ f\circ\ell_3^{-1}.
$$
In particular:
$$
f\circ(\ell_1^{-1}\circ\ell_2)=(\tilde{\ell}_2^{-1}\circ\tilde{\ell}_1)\circ f,\quad f\circ(\ell_1^{-1}\circ\ell_3)=(\tilde{\ell}_3^{-1}\circ\tilde{\ell}_3)\circ f.
$$
In these functional equations, the slopes of affine transformations $\ell_1^{-1}\circ\ell_2$ and $\ell_1^{-1}\circ\ell_3$ are non-zero, and moreover different from $\pm 1$ since we had $m_1\neq\pm m_2,\pm m_3$.  Hence the lemma below can be applied: If $f$ is not affine, then there exist $\alpha\in\Bbb{R}$ with $\ell_1^{-1}\circ\ell_2(\alpha)=\ell_1^{-1}\circ\ell_3=\alpha$. But then $\ell_1(\alpha)=\ell_2(\alpha)=\ell_3(\alpha)$, i.e.  $L'_1,L'_2,L'_3$ are concurrent, a contradiction.
Lemma) Let $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ be an analytic function which is not affine (i.e. not of the form $x\mapsto ax+b$). All affine transformations $u$ with slope different from $0$ and $\pm 1$ for which the composition $f\circ u$ is an affine transformation of  $f$ share a fixed point
Proof of the lemma) Let $u$ be one such function: $u(x)=ax+b$ where $a\neq 0,\pm 1$ and $f\circ u$ is equal to $v\circ f$ for a function $v$ of the same form.  Since $a \neq 1$, $u$ admits a unique fixed point $x_0$.
Evaluating $v\circ f=f\circ u$ at $x_0$ shows that $v(f(x_0))=f(x_0)$. Since $x_0$ and $f(x_0)$ are fixed points of affine transformations $u$ and $v$ respectively, $u$ and $v$ can be written as
$$
u(x)=a(x-x_0)+x_0,\quad v(x)=a'(x-f(x_0))+f(x_0).
$$
Therefore, $v\circ f=f\circ u$ amounts to
$$
a'(f(x)-f(x_0))=f(a(x-x_0)+x_0)-f(x_0).
$$
Consider the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $x_0$: $f(x)-f(x_0)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k(x-x_0)^k$. Substituting it in the equation above, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty a'c_k(x-x_0)^k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_ka^k(x-x_0)^k
$$
for $x$ from an open interval centered at $x_0$. Equating the coefficients of the power series: $c_k\left(1-\frac{a'}{a^k}\right)=0\,\,\forall k\geq 1$.   Since $f$ is not affine, there exists $k_*>1$ with $c_{k_*}\neq 0$. Thus $a'=a^{k_*}$. For any other $k$, one has $1-\frac{a'}{a^k}\neq 0$ due to $a\neq\pm 1$, which implies $c_k=0$ for all positive integers $k$ except $k_*$. We conclude that $f(x)=c_{k_*}(x-x_0)^{k_*}+f(x_0)$. But when $k_*>1$, a representation of the form $\beta(x-\alpha)^{k_*}+\gamma$ is unique. Hence any other affine transformation satisfying the properties of $u$ must have $x_0$ as a fixed point.

The analyticity assumption makes this less useful for my present purpose, but it's a beautiful result and I can imagine it being very useful in the future.  Thanks for sharing it.
